# How can I call a function from javascript module in html onclick

Tags: javascript, html, module

```html
<h1 onclick="sayhello()"> Hello Word</h1>

<script type="module" >
        sayhello=()=>{
            console.log('Hello');
        }
</script>
```

result is: `(index):14 Uncaught ReferenceError: sayhello is not defined at (index):14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button onclick="hellosay()">Click</button>
<script type="module">
  window.hellosay=()=>{
  console.log("hello")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should either remove `type=module`:

```html
<h1 onclick="sayhello()">Click</h1>
<script  >
    sayhello=()=>{
        console.log('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

Or attach the function to `window` to use it globally:

```html
<h1 onclick="sayhello()">Click</h1>
<script type="module">
    window.sayhello=()=>{
        console.log('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any disadvantages to attaching the function to window to use it globally?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your script should look like:

```
<script>
  function sayHello(){  
    console.log('hello')
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use module system in my project.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript modules create a .js or .mjs file and export your javascript functions

Mymodule.js

```
export function sayHell(){
    console.log("ok");
}
```

and import it.

Samples here https://github.com/mdn/js-examples/tree/master/modules/basic-modules

Documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Thank guy, I already got it by calling window object.